# Trouble installing cPanel

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, centos, cpanel, whm

I am trying to install the latest version of cPanel on a server running Centos 6.6 and it is failing here:

```
[20150129.112152]   Testing if it's possible to install a simple RPM
[20150129.112152]   Retrieving http://httpupdate.cpanel.net/RPM/rpm_is_working-1.0-0.noarch.rpm
[20150129.112152]   Preparing...                ##################################################
[20150129.112152]   rpm_is_working              ##################################################
[20150129.112152]   Now removing the RPM
info [updatenow] upcp Notification => root@server.serveraddress.com via EMAIL [level => 1]
Cpanel::iContact: icontact /usr/sbin/sendmail is not executable by 0
[20150129.112152] W An attempt to up/downgrade to 11.46.2.4 was blocked. Please review blockers.
Can't exec "/usr/local/cpanel/scripts/cpanel_initial_install": No such file or directory at 
/home/cPanelInstall/selfgz11290/install line 146.
2015-01-29 11:21:52  148 (FATAL): Failure to exec /usr/local/cpanel/scripts/cpanel_initial_install
Removing /root/installer.lock
```

Does anyone have any ideas? I am trying to install this on an AWS EC2 instance that is running Centos 6.6. I tried opening my security group so that all traffic is allowed and this did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be resulted from the failure of downloading essential files. I solved this problem on my server simply by clear `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` and stop the iptables service by `service iptables stop`.

What's more, I also delete `~/.cpan/`, `~/.cpanm/`, `~/.cpcpan/` and `~/cPanelInstall`.